# Equal distance between children when using grid and flex

Tags: css, flexbox, grid

I have this sample:

[link](https://codepen.io/dcrysty23/pen/mdMXQvB)

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h6 {
  background: red;
}

.pre-el {
  background: gray;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.pre-el:first-child {
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.pre-el:last-child {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="pre-el">
    <h6>Title 1</h6>
  </div>
  <div class="pre-el">
    <h6>Title 2</h6>
  </div>
  <div class="pre-el">
    <h6>Title 3</h6>
  </div>
  <div class="pre-el">
    <h6>Title 4</h6>
  </div>
</div>
```

The first column and the last column must have the content on the left and on the right, respectively.

This makes the space between the elements no longer equal.

For example, the distance between `"title 1"` and `"title 2"` is not equal to the distance between `"title 2"` and `"title 3"`.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you had equal space, the grey boxes wouldn't be the same size as each other - the first and last would be smaller than the middle 2

Comment: ok and how can i do this?
that I've been looking for information and I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: if you want the grey boxes like that, you will have to guess at the sizes to make the text equal spaced (see top example in following link), otherwise you could use flex and  justify content to get your items properly evenly spaced (bottom example): https://jsfiddle.net/ynthd2a0/1/